# how to add new tables to my database without losing the data of the previous tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to migrate my new tables to the mysql database and I don't want to lose the data of the previous tables that already existed , which command should I use instead of `php artisan migrate`

Comment: If by tables you mean an SQL with CREATE, why don't you just import the SQL? You want to auto-generate migrations/seeds?

Comment: I use Laravel and its related automatically the the database , I think bro the question is clear !

Comment: Check this article my help You. https://dev.to/mahmudulhsn/update-existing-table-with-migration-without-losing-in-data-in-laravel-fb1

Comment: What have you tried so far? Running `CREATE TABLE` does usually not affect any other table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you want to do when creating the migration file and running it using `php artisan migrate` :

- `Schema::create()` will create a new table. Will not affect existing data
- `Schema::table()` will modify your table, usually used to add columns. Will not affect the exsting data.
- `Schema::rename()` will rename the table. Will not affect the exsting data.
- `Schema::drop()` will delete the table. Will affect the existing data.

You will need to see the status of the migration you created earlier using :

```
php migrate:status
```

```
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Ran? | Migration                                             | Batch |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Yes  | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table                  | 1     |
| Yes  | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table        | 1     |
| Yes  | 2015_10_12_100000_create_vendors_table                | 1     |
| Yes  | 2015_10_12_100001_create_channels_table               | 1     |
| Yes  | 2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table       | 1     |
| Yes  | 2016_06_01_000002_create_oauth_access_tokens_table    | 1     |
| Yes  | 2016_06_01_000003_create_oauth_refresh_tokens_table   | 1     |
| Yes  | 2016_06_01_000004_create_oauth_clients_table          | 1     |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

```
migrate              Run the database migrations
migrate:fresh        Drop all tables and re-run all migrations
migrate:install      Create the migration repository
migrate:refresh      Reset and re-run all migrations
migrate:reset        Rollback all database migrations
migrate:rollback     Rollback the last database migration
migrate:status       Show the status of each migration
```

Answer (score 1):

I preferred to create it in another folder
from this commend

```
php artisan make:migration new_table_name --path=database/migrations/new_folder_name
```

and run migration from

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/new_folder_name
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a migration to create a new table, Running the command `php artisan migrate` will not affect the other tables It will apply the new changes only.
if you have migrated your tables before and you want to create a new table you can create a new migration file and run the command `php artisan migrate` it will create the new table only.